# Getting Oledb exception when updating column in excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am getting the following error "No value given for one or more required parameters." On the ExceuteNonQuery() line of the below code.

```
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection finalConnection;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        string sql = null;
        finalConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source ='c:\\temp\\test.xlsx'; Extended Properties ='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO';");
        finalConnection.Open();
        myCommand.Connection = finalConnection;
        foreach (VinObject v in VinList)
            {
            sql = "Update [Sheet1$] set O = ? where S = ?;";
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@amt", v.CostNewAmt));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@vin", v.VIN));
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        finalConnection.Close();
```

I have also tried using a separate command each time, same error.

```
    foreach (VinObject v in VinList)
            {
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source ='c:\\temp\\test.xlsx'; Extended Properties ='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No';"))
                {
                con.Open();
                string query = @"UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET O = ? WHERE S = ?";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", v.CostNewAmt);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", v.VIN);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                }
            }
```

I am able to modify that into an insert and insert into a new excel spreadsheet, but for the life of me cannot get this update to work. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a new command for each individual statement? Or at the least, reset the Parameters collection?

Comment: hint: What is the value of 'sql' inside your foreach?  Does this look like a valid query to you?

Comment: @ValAkkapeddi it bombs on the first one, and the query is valid at that point

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because Excel doesn't recognize the column letter aliases "O" and "S". It needs the actual column "name", which is the value of the cell in the first populated row. If there is not a valid value in that cell, or you have specified `HDR=NO` in your connection string, the columns will be named `F1`, `F2`...`Fn`. If you're not sure what the inferred column names are, examine the names using [**`OleDbConnection.GetSchema(String,String[])`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135983.aspx) or [**`OleDbDataReader.GetName(Int32)`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getname.aspx).

Since you have specified `HDR=NO` in your connection string, your correct SQL will likely be

```
"Update [Sheet1$] set F15 = ? where F19 = ?;"
```

For future reference, check out:

- [How to query and display excel data by using ASP.NET, ADO.NET, and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306572)
- [How to transfer data to an Excel workbook by using Visual C# 2005 or Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306023)
- [How To Use ADO.NET to Retrieve and Modify Records in an Excel Workbook With Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934). (Still lots of helpful info even if you are using C#)

Comment: that did not fix my error sadly, I still get the same error when i replace the letters with the "Fn" values. any other advice? thanks

Comment: @IsaacLevin Did you examine the actual column names using OleDbConnection.GetSchema or OleDbDataReader.GetName? The documentation is linked in my post

Comment: What about the date filed. I have date column as [$-1010409] mm/dd/yyyy format and when i tried to put this in where clause like string selectString = "Update [Sheet1$] set SCIN_ATTEND_CODE = 'P' where SCIN_INVOICE_DAYS = 09/09/2014"; its not recognize and didnt update anything. i tried with adding '' around date but it gives datatype mismatch error.. Any idea?